# data model n<->n relationship that I don't understand

Tags: mysql, database-design

I  will use a data model for a vehicle database and I will use a diagram found in databaseanswers.com but there is a thing that I don't understand.

[Database Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7Bj.gif)

In this diagram there is a table `"vehicle_model_categories"` which makes the relationship between the tables `"vehicle_models"` and `"vehicle_category"`, until then it is good but the table `"vehicles"` also makes the relationship between these two tables, Does not understand what the `"vehicle_model_categories"` table might serve. Would it not have been better to add an index to the table `"vehicule_model_categories"` and make the relationship in the table `"vehicles"`?

I am not a database modeling specialist, sorry if my question seems somewhat stupid but I am trying to understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vehicles` is about individual vehicles.  Imagine there can be 100M vehicles in the US.  `Vehicle_Categories` is a much more smaller set, perhaps only 20-100 categories (e.g. Compact, Convertible, etc).  `Vehicle_Models` is also a relatively smaller set, perhaps not more than 2,000 (e.g. VW Beetle, VW GTi).  There certainly is a relationship between entities in the last two sets.  For example, "VW Beetle" may be classified as "Compact" as its category.  This relationship is relatively small (e.g. 100 categories for 2,000 model).  It is good to have a small table (perhaps only 2000 entries) that captures this relationship so that question such as these can be quickly answered:

1. What category is the model "VW Beetle"?
2. What are the models in the category "Compact"?

If we drop the table `Vehicle_Model_Categories` and express the relationship only in the table `Vehicles`, then the queries to the above questions will have to search a much larger table of ~100M entries.

*Redundant Information*

So strictly speaking, the DB design has some redundancy in it, but it is
not in the table `Vehicle_Model_Categories`, but in the column
`Vehicles.Vehicle_Category_Code`.  This information is redundant
because one can write a query with a `JOIN` of the table `Vehicles` *without*
the column (but has column `Model_Code`) and the table `Vehicle_Model_Categories` and still get the information
about `Vehicle_Category_Code`.  This redundancy has its own
pros and cons.

- Pros: It may speed up the access of `Vehicles` and making the information
  more readily available (i.e. no need to JOIN with `Vehicle_Model_Categories`)
- Cons: When information is redundant, it is more easy to get
  inconsistent information.  For example, if one day, a model get 
  re-classified into a new category (e.g. "VW Beetle" is now classified
  as "Compact - Classifical"), then all the `Vehicle_Cetegory_Code` 
  information in `Vehicles` would have to be updated.

Comment: Hi @leeyuiwah, thanks for your response, if I understand, it's just for search optimization ?

Comment: @aliasdoc -- Yes.  But I also added some discussion about redundant information to my answer above.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @leeyuiwah for your explanation, I understand and I think I will delete the `Vehicles.Vehicle_Category_Code`relationship to avoid redundancy